# dynamically add/remove input type file (browser field)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a input type file field and there is a label near this like "Add more",this is a hyper link. While clicking on this hyper link it should create another input type file field. Once it is created an another input type file field there should be link like "Remove", clicking on this link will remove the corresponding file field only.

Note that there is no limit of adding this file fields, but in worst case I will upto 10 file fields maximun. I meant to say there should be no condition to check whether it reached the maximum limit.

You can see my code here.http://jsfiddle.net/inDiscover/6hVkw/

## HTML

```
<table>
<tr id="bkup_doc_rw">
<td align="right"><label class="letter_font" for="bkup_doc_proof">Document &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</label></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="file" name="bkup_doc_proof" id="bkup_doc_proof" required/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="letter_font" style="text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer;" href="#" id="addNew">Add more </a>
</td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

## JQUERY

```
var fle_cnt = 1;
$('#addNew').click(function() {
fle_cnt++;
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;  
$('#bkup_doc_rw').after('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input   type="file" name="bkup_doc_proof" id="bkup_doc_proof_'+fle_cnt+'">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="letter_font" style="text-decoration: none;cursor: pointer;" href="#" id="remNew">Remove</a></td></tr>');
return false;
});

$(document).on('click', '#remNew', function() {
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
$('#remNew').parents('tr').remove();    
return false;   
});
```

Here issue is when I tried to clike on "Remove" label it is not removing the corresponding file field instead it is removing randomly. I know this issue is happening because I am not using unique ID (file_cnt) while deleting a filed.

Can any one help me to modify my code in a better way to achieve this.

Comment: `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`!? there's CSS and `margin-left` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   var fle_cnt = 1;
   $('#addNew').click(function (event) {
       fle_cnt++;
       event.preventDefault();
       $('#bkup_doc_rw').after('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="file" name="bkup_doc_proof" id="bkup_doc_proof_' + fle_cnt + '"><a class="letter_font remNew" style="text-decoration: none;cursor: pointer;" href="#">Remove</a></td></tr>');
   });

   $(document).on('click', '.remNew', function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $(this).closest('tr').remove();
   });
```

changes:

1. in the `#addNew` click pass the event in the callback.
2. change the `id` attribute to `class` instead.
3. instead of id selector change to the class selector `.remNew`.
4. instead of `$('#remNew')` place the context selector as `$(this)`.
5. pass the event in the callback of `.remNew`'s click event
6. You don't need to use `return false;` as you are already using `event.preventDefault();` and it would work if you pass the event in the callback as mentioned above.
7. and instead of `.parents()` use `.closest()` to traverse up.

### [Demo @ updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6hVkw/2/)

Comment: I have two questions here. 1] If I am passing the event in the callback function and if I am using event.preventDefault() then I dont need to use "return false" right??. Otherwise I need to use. Right?? 2]Why I need to change id attribute to class??.If I am using id attribute than also it will work right?? Is there any specific reason. 3]Also I would like to know why closest() instead of parents().

Comment: @user3742125 for [1] see `return false;` does two things a) preventing the default behavior and b) stop the event to bubbleup in the dom. so if there is no need to stop the event bubbling then should not be used otherwise `return false;` is good to go. now [2] see you have to give unique ids per element if you don't do this then only first elem will be the one which gets the event. or i must say that makes a invalid markup against w3c recommendations.

Comment: I am pointing to ur quote "if you don't do this then only first elem will be the one which gets the event". What you meant by the first element which gets the event. Here you are giving a common class similarly I am giving a common id ,provided i am not using this id any where.Or is this just a standard to follow.

Comment: see same ids are not good practice to follow ids should be unique per element in a single page. for a collection of selectors you can use classname which can be applied to multiple elements in a single page and that is a valid selector and valid markup, also to be notice same ids in a single page can raise issues if you want to make your application cross browser compatible, because all the browsers have their own dom api implementation so advice is to use classnames.

Answer (score 0):

`#remNew` That why ! 
IDs  are mean to be unique.

`$('#remNew').parents('tr').remove();` 
to 
`$(this).parents('tr').remove();`

Answer (score 0):

htry this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.letter_font', function() {
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
    $(this).parents('tr').remove(); 
    return false;   
});
```

inside the click event use $(this).  this way you can manage the exact object which triggered the event.

Answer (score 0):

HTML pages must have the ID's unique. Make the `remNew` a class and you're fine:

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hVkw/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var fle_cnt = 1;
$('#addNew').click(function() {
    fle_cnt++;
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;  
    $('#bkup_doc_rw').after('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="file" name="bkup_doc_proof" id="bkup_doc_proof_'+fle_cnt+'" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="letter_font remNew" style="text-decoration: none;cursor: pointer;" href="#" >Remove</a></td></tr>');
    return false;
});

$(document).on('click', '.remNew', function() {
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    return false;   
});
```

You were using id = "remNew", should never use multiple id's - they are used specially to create unique identification,
for DOM elements with similar property we always use classes - so i replaced id with class = "remNew"

on click on some elements we able to detect it using **this** instance , and the use jquery **closest** to delete specific tr tag

Answer (score 0):

make remNew as class, you can try this way too

```
 `http://jsfiddle.net/MRqN4/`
```